# How to have header and footer inside of container?

Tags: html, css

I need the appropriate Html and CSS for the following

Here is the layout of the app

```
   Detailed Figure                      General Figure

-------------------------         -------------------------
|    App Header         |         |    App Header         |
-------------------------         -------------------------
| Module Header|  Sub   |         |              |        |
|--------------| Module |         |              |        |
|              |--------|         |              |        |
|  Module      |  Sub   |         |    Main      | Sub    |
|  Content     | Module |         |    Module    | Module |
|              |--------|         |    Space     | Space  |
|              |  Sub   |         |              |        |
|--------------| Module |         |              |        |
|  Module      |--------|         |              |        |
|  Footer      |        |         |              |        |
-------------------------         -------------------------
```

App Header is a static 60px
Module Header is a static 35px
Module Content is dynamic and overflows
Module Footer is dynamic and needs to always display everything on screen (it would never be more than say 500px)

What is the appropriate way to setup the Main Module Space and children?
How do I get the Headers and Footers to understand they're in containers and should not cover the entire width of the screen?

(I've used absolute position for the footer but that causes Module Content to hide behind the Module Footer)

Comment: Try using [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: I would recommend taking some Codecademy or TeamTreehouse courses on HTML/CSS. There's plenty of free courses on YouTube as well if you don't want to fork out any money. You need to bolster your understanding of web fundamentals.

Comment: It would seem people don't like this question, can anyone explain why?

Comment: @moondc your question is very broad and you have not shared any code showing how you have attempted this. The expectation of this site is that your question is specific and reproducible using code you provide. If you dont have any code a broad question like this is likely to only yield opinion based answers and so it is considered off-topic. There are plenty of helpful articles that can show you how to craft your question. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for the most part
https://jsfiddle.net/jackyFrosty/46mjtghv/47/

```html
<div class='mainApp'>
  <div class='appHeader'>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class='contentContainer'>
    <div class='leftContainer'>
      <div class='moduleContainer'>    
        <header class='header'>
          Header
        </header>
        <main class='content'>
          <div>Content 1</div><div>Content 2</div><div>Content 3</div><div>Content 4</div>
          <div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div>
          <div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div><div>Content</div>
          <div>Content 96</div><div>Content 97</div><div>Content 98</div><div>Content 99</div>
        </main>
        <footer class='footer'>
          <div>Footer</div><div>Footer</div><div>Footer</div><div>Footer</div>
          <!--div>Footer</div><div>Footer</div><div>Footer</div><div>Footer</div-->
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='rightContainer'>
      Right Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.mainApp {
  height: 100%;
}

.appHeader {
  height: 60px;
  border-color: black;
}

.contentContainer {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}

.leftContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
 border-color: black;
}

.rightContainer {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 border-color: black;
}

/* /////////// Important part ////////// */
.moduleContainer {
  border-color: orange;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}

.header {
  border-color: red;
  height: 35px;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content {
  border-color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.footer {
  border-color: blue;
}
```